# Solving triple integral with variable bounds based on outer integral

Tags: r

The current code I have is below. The equation I'm trying to solve is below as well. It can be solved in wolfram alpha but I'm unable to get R to perform it.

```
library(pracma)
fun <- function(x,y) {exp(-(x+y))}
fun2 <- function(z) {integral2(fun, 0, z, 0, 2-z)$Q}
integral(fun2, 0, 2)
```

Copy this into wolfram alpha to see the pretty text:

integral_0^(1) integral_0^z integral_0^(2-z) e^(-(x+y)) dx dy dz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:
`integral` needs a vectorized function.

```
library(pracma)
fun <- function(x,y) {exp(-(x+y))}
fun2 <- function(z) {integral2(fun, 0, 2-z, 0, z)$Q}
Fun2 <- Vectorize(fun2)
integral(Fun2, 0, 1)
# [1] 0.2706706
```

Of course, Wolfram Alpha returns a symbolic solution and
will thus be more exact. Still, R's result is quite good.